# "Pin" a workspace on external monitor (projector)

Tags: multiple-monitors, arch-linux, xfce, gnome3, workspace

I would like to have a setup with two workspaces and two monitors (built-in screen and a projector).

I wish to have the second workspace always visible on the projector while being able to switch workspaces on the built-in screen.

Is this possible with Gnome 3.20 or with XFCE? How would I go about it?